# Insert the password in a one liner command

Tags: bash, sh, ksh

So i'm planning of creating a script for a cluster aware setup where it has an admin layer and a diagnostic layer wherein you can run an advanced commands which is unavailable on the admin layer.
But the thing is before you can enter into the diagnostic layer, you need to input the password and on that same line, you need to run a couple of commands so that you are still on that diag level coz if you add that command on the next line it will return an error coz basically you're already running that command on the admin layer.

`'diag d -c off; systemshell -node nodename;` <-- this is where the password is being asked

This is what i'm trying to achieve once password has been entered after systemshell.
`'diag d -c off; systemshell -node nodename; next command here; next command here; next command here`

I tried using pipe (echo and cat) but it's not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you using a pipe? What's probably happening is that `next command here` is supposed to be input to `systemshell` itself, not the next command for the shell to execute *after* `systemshell` has exited.

Comment: This is how i used the pipe command.
`echo 'password0!' | ssh -i key.pub admin@123 'diag d -c off; systemshell -node nodename'` yes, `next command here` is an input to systemshell and should be ran while you're on the systemshell (diag layer).

Comment: You'll need something like `systemshell -node nodename -c "next command here; next command here"` (if `systemshell` has an option for specifying the command to execute) or use a [here document](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents).

Comment: `systemshell -node nodename -c` this command will not work since `-c` is not recognized on the admin layer